# I am facing issue with positioning of one element over another using html and css

Tags: html, css

I have 2 div elements in which I want to place a portion of second element on top of the first element for that I gave position relative to second element and from bottom 50px. But I place another div after second element I am getting some space in between. How to avoid that space.

Here's my code sample

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
  <div style="height:100px;background-color:red;"></div>
  <div style="height:100px;background-color:green;width:250px;margin:0 auto;position:relative;bottom:50px;"></div>
  <p style="text-align:center;">Hello am here</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FHRQQ7D92JKP

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position:relative;bottom:50px` and replace with `margin:-50px auto 0;`

Let me know if works.
cheers!